# How to write a LLVM pass with prerequisited transformation using new pass manager?

Tags: llvm

With the legacy pass manager, as for my custom function pass,
I can run it with legacy pass manager like this, `opt -custom-pass`.

And I can also made it depends on `LoopSimplify` form by doing this.

```
void CustomPass::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage& AU) const {
  AU.addRequiredID(LoopSimplifyID);
}
```

Using the new pass manager, I think the `getAnalysisUsage()` function and the concept of dependency are removed.

I am wondering how can I code my custom **function pass** to reproduce the above feature.

To be more clear
I want to make `custom-pass` automatically depend on `LoopSimplify` pass and invoke it by `opt -passes='custom-pass'` instead of `opt -passes='loop-simplify,custom-pass'`.